# Google Chrome extensions - how to see what extensions are enabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm setting up a new computer, and am trying to recreate my old Google Chrome environment.

I can see which extensions I had installed by extracting out the extension names from each extension's manifest.json file, but can't figure out how to gell whether that extension was enabled or not in my previous install.

Where is the enabled status of an extension stored for Google Chrome?

Comment: so are you trying to see whether the extension was enabled from Chrome, or from the manifest file? If you're looking in the manifest file - there is nothing in it to tell you whether the extension is enabled or not.

Answer (score -2):

According to google by simply logging in to your google account your extensions will be synched.

> To see your extensions on any computer or device you use, simply sign in to your Google Account on Chrome. Your extensions will be automatically synced.

Source: Manage your extensions https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en

Comment: I need to be able to do it by looking at the file system. My previous set up did not have the google account synced